# JSON data from an unpublished Google Drive Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-sheets, drive

So I know that it's possible to capture JSON data from a published sheet:

```
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1wmjkZdtR43hvMoQwdgRDNo8PBYulrKh7Q6YmdivtTh0/od6/public/basic?alt=json", function(data){

                    //console.log(data);

                    var cells = data.feed.entry;

                    //console.log(cells);

                    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){

                        console.log('cell: ', cells[i].title.$t, 'data: ', cells[i].content.$t);

                    };

                });
```

...but can I capture data from an unpublished sheet? I have a client id and I figured with this extra variable, one could capture private data.

Comment: You may not be able to for unpublished sheets. Check out the sheets api docs.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#sheets_api_urls_visibilities_and_projections

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate with OAuth 2.0.
See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet-to-json,  how they use OAuth 2.0 to get private spreadsheets.